# Ternary operator with branches with void type

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, conditional-operator

Is it safe to use ternary operator with functions which return void? Something like this:

```
void foo1(){}
void foo2(){}

//////////////

bool to_use_1 = ....;
to_use_1 ? foo1() : foo2();
```

Can compiler delete this code? Suppose it will treats such functions as pure, and perform agressive optimization which delete these calls

Comment: foo1 will execute if to_use_1 is true, foo2 otherwise. It's perfectly safe. Whether you want to or not is a matter for you and your coding standards.

Comment: _"...which delete these calls"_ only under the "as-if-rule" the compiler can prove that foo1 and/or foo2 have no side affects.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition are right.

Comment: It's statement containing expression. It's always evaluated. Also, just `foo1();` is expression statement too. Optimization only makes changes which don't change results (values, returns, side-effects,... ). Optimizations mustn't change program behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the compiler will/should never logically "delete" any calls that have observable effects (with the sole exception of *[copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)*). That's simply not something it's allowed to do, no matter how aggressive the optimisation mode.

The C++ standard in fact makes explicit allowance for the result of your conditional operator's operands to be `void`, so this is expected and safe. However, it does have to be *both*.

> `[C++14: 5.16/1]:` Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). **It is evaluated and if it is true, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the second expression, otherwise that of the third expression. Only one of the second and third expressions is evaluated.** Every value computation and side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the second or third expression.
>
> `[C++14: 5.16/2]:` If either the second or the third operand has type `void`, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) *throw-expression* (15.1); the result is of the type and value category of the other.
> - **Both the second and the third operands have type `void`; the result is of type `void` and is a prvalue.** *[ Note:* This includes the case where both operands are *throw-expressions*. *—end note ]*

Technically, this wording (in its talk about "values") doesn't outright spell out that *exactly* one of the second and third expressions is evaluated, even when those evaluations have no "value". But it's essentially indisputable from the standpoint of analysis. There *may* be a case for an editorial improvement here.

Note that none of this guarantees that your computer will *actually* jump, during execution, into `foo1` or `foo2`; in the specific example you give, the compiler can immediately see that both functions are completely empty, and optimise away the entire line of code. But that does not affect the semantics of your program, nor is it specific to use of the conditional operator.

Comment: I don't agree with you, I have saw deletion of copy constructors with side effects (see copy elision)

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Okay, granted. I have made that clearer.

Comment: Plus 1 for C++14 reference (actually for Emilia Clarke :))

Comment: Actually, /6, in its talk about lvalue-to-rvalue conversions, may take care of the perceived editorial ambiguity. But it'll take a better language lawyer than me to confirm or deny that.